# Infinite calculation of Photos and System Data on MBP Air M2(16/256) Ventura

Tags: macos

I have inifinite calculation of Photos and System Data in system setting. Dont know what to do with that. I don't have any photos on this laptop, so it looks like bug in the system.

[image: storage]

Maybe someone know how to resolve it?

Already tried:

1. Reboot
2. First Aid in Disk Utility
3. Disconnect all peripherals

Need to mention, that icloud sync is disabled on this laptop.

Cheers
Denis

Comment: It’s likely a bug as you’ve already indicated.  It’s not clear what your expectations are.  Is it causing a problem that’s interfering with your workflow?  Did you leave feedback at https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html?

Comment: Yes. Already did it via Feedback Assistant

Comment: I've encountered this recently, do you have any insights? I had iCloud Drive enabled and then disabled it if that helps.

Comment: Hi @DanS! Could you edit this post to list your macOS version (and build if possible) I’m guessing both photos and system only are stuck for you as well? Any other information you can provide might help

Comment: Hi. Sorry for late reply, but i resolved the problem via recreating Photos library folder. The problem was half in me - i deleted the folder, because dont use any icloud sync - so after that macos stuck at size calculations.

Comment: Thanks for coming back. Why not post your solution as an answer below and accept it?